# How can i return the values of a void function

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that calculate the fft of the mic input.
The target is to create a framework when i call the run function the i ged the float array with all bands.

Now it work all fine, but i don't know how can i return the Array in the run function from the gotSomeAudio function.

Thank you very much for help

```
@objc
public class FFT:NSObject{


    var audioInput: TempiAudioInput!

    @objc
    public func run() -> Array<Float>{

        let audioInputCallback: TempiAudioInputCallback = { (numberOfFrames, timeStamp, inout samples: [Float]) -> Void in
            self.gotSomeAudio(numberOfFrames, timeStamp: timeStamp, samples: samples)
        }


        audioInput = TempiAudioInput(audioInputCallback: audioInputCallback, sampleRate: 44100, numberOfChannels: 1)
        audioInput.startRecording()

        // how can i return the Array from the gotSomeAudio function? 
        return xyz
    }




    @objc
    public func gotSomeAudio(numberOfFrames: Int, timeStamp: Double, samples: [Float]) -> Array<Float> {

        let fft = TempiFFT(withSize: numberOfFrames, sampleRate: 44100)

        // Setting a window type reduces errors
        fft.windowType = TempiFFTWindowType.hanning

        // Perform the FFT
        fft.fftForward(samples)

        // Map FFT data to logical bands. This gives 4 bands per octave across 7 octaves = 28 bands.
        //fft.calculateLogarithmicBands(minFrequency: 100, maxFrequency: 11025, bandsPerOctave: 4)
        //fft.calculateLinearBands(minFrequency: 0, maxFrequency: fft.nyquistFrequency, numberOfBands: Int(screenWidth))
        fft.calculateLogarithmicBands(minFrequency: 100, maxFrequency: 11025, bandsPerOctave: 4)

        // Process some data
        return fft.bandFrequencies

    }

}
```

Comment: You can create an object of `Array<Float>` say `bandFreqs`, loop through all values of `fft.bandFrequencies` and then add values to `bandFreqs` and return `bandFreqs` array.

Comment: thank you, do you have an example, sorry i'm new to swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it to a callback function:

```
public func run(complete: Array<Float> -> Void) {

    let audioInputCallback: TempiAudioInputCallback = { (numberOfFrames, timeStamp, inout samples: [Float]) -> Void in
        complete(self.gotSomeAudio(numberOfFrames, timeStamp: timeStamp, samples: samples))
    }

...
```

---

```
myInstance.run() { floatArray in
    // Use floatArray here.
}
```

Comment: how can i access the data when i calling the run function?